# Spring MVC @RestController -> PUTting results in "400 Bad Request" no matter what I do

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-restcontroller

I have a Spring RestController which works great when I `GET` data from it, but when I try to `PUT` the *very same data*, I get a `400 Bad Request`.

Here is the simplest version of my controller that **should** still work (I left out the `GET` method):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/configuration/ledstrips/{name}/display")
public class DisplayController {

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = { "application/hal+json" })
    public DisplayResource setDisplay(@PathVariable String name, @RequestBody DisplayResource display) {

        return display;
    }
}
```

This is the `DisplayResource`:

```
public class DisplayResource extends ResourceSupport {

    private List<Color> pixels;

    public List<Color> getPixels() {

        return pixels;
    }


    public void setPixels(List<Color> pixels) {

        this.pixels = pixels;
    }
}
```

I pretty much copied this code over from another branch, and there it works!

I can't figure it out!

**EDIT**

Here's the `GET`-Method:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/hal+json" })
public DisplayResource getDisplay(@PathVariable String name) {

    LEDStripDTO ledStripDTO;

    try {
        ledStripDTO = ledStripDTOService.getDTO(name);
    } catch (IOException | NullPointerException exception) {
        throw new LoadFailedException("Error loading LED strip:", exception);
    }

    Link self = linkTo(methodOn(DisplayController.class).getDisplay(name)).withSelfRel();

    DisplayResource displayResource = new DisplayResource();

    displayResource.add(self);

    try {
        displayResource.setPixels(ledStripService.getPixels(ledStripDTO));
    } catch (IOException | TimeoutException | AlreadyConnectedException | NotConnectedException exception) {
        throw new LoadFailedException("Error getting Information from LED strip:", exception);
    }

    return displayResource;
}
```

And a result it produces (for a LED strip of length 1):

```
{
  "pixels": [
    {
      "red": 0,
      "green": 16,
      "blue": 0
    }
  ],
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/configuration/ledstrips/devled/display"
    }
  }
}
```

When I send this, be it with or without the `_links` segment, I get a `400` error.

Comment: Since I said, I copied it over from another branch. The only difference in dependencies is Spring Data on the older branch. I just put it back in and, predictably, it didn't make any difference.

Comment: And what does the PUT request itself look like?

Comment: @Raedwald The simples PUT request has the header `Content-Type` set to `application/json` and the body `{"pixels":[{"red":0,"green":0,"blue":0}]}`, which is a much reduced version of what I get from the `GET`-method. It should switch the first LED to black.

Comment: If anybody wants to try for themselves: https://github.com/synyx/sybil/tree/newpackage (ignore the README, I haven't updated it yet. Also ignore the horrible code in the master branch please ;) ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>As it's a `PUT`, you've defined a `produces` but not a `consumes`. It could be that the endpoint doesn't know what format to expect the body in, which is why it's rejecting it. Try:</strike>

Having looked at the source you've provided, I can see that the `Color` class has a constructor that requires arguments. The default `ObjectMapper` provided by the Jackson libraries won't be able to unmarshall a JSON string due to this constructor. Try adding a default constructor to the `Color` class along side the current one:

```
public Color(int red, int green, int blue) {

    this.red = setColorLimits(red);
    this.green = setColorLimits(green);
    this.blue = setColorLimits(blue);
}

public Color() {}
```